# Playframework 2.3.9 sbt building on heroku fails on import

Tags: java, scala, heroku, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to deploy my play 2.3.9 app to heroku. After updating and downloading the libs, sbt fails on an strange import error with the following error messsge:

```
remote:        [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
remote:        /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/modules/admin/build.sbt:0: error: not found: object $34400878e902ee641868
remote:        import $34400878e902ee641868._
remote:               ^
remote:        [error] Type error in expression
remote:        Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? 
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to run sbt!
```

The app is using 3 submodules called admin, common and web and apparently is failing on the build.sbt file of the admin module.

The build.sbt file of the admin module is partially generated by by a common scala object named Common.scala hosted in the "project" folder of the root module. This common object is used by admin, common and web submodules in order to share common build properties.

Admin's build.sbt:

```
Common.moduleSettings("admin")

lazy val common = (project in file("../common")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).enablePlugins(SbtWeb).dependsOn(common).aggregate(common)

Keys.fork in (Test) := false

libraryDependencies ++= Common.commonDependencies
```

The Common.scala file:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._
import play.PlayImport._
import com.typesafe.sbt.web.SbtWeb.autoImport.{Assets, pipelineStages}
import com.typesafe.sbt.less.Import.LessKeys
import com.typesafe.sbt.rjs.Import.{rjs, RjsKeys}
import com.typesafe.sbt.digest.Import.digest

object Common {
  def appName = "lcdp-1"

  // Common settings for every project
  def settings (theName: String) = Seq(
    name := theName,
    organization := "com.lcdp",
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.6",
    doc in Compile <<= target.map(_ / "none"),
    scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature", "-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-language:reflectiveCalls"),
    resolvers += "sonatype snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
    resolvers += "release repository" at  "http://hakandilek.github.com/maven-repo/releases/",
    resolvers += "snapshot repository" at "http://hakandilek.github.com/maven-repo/snapshots/"
  )
  // Settings for the app, i.e. the root project
  val appSettings = settings(appName) ++: Seq(
    javaOptions += s"-Dconfig.resource=root.conf"
  )
  // Settings for every module, i.e. for every subproject
  def moduleSettings (module: String) = settings(module) ++: Seq(
    javaOptions += s"-Dconfig.resource=$module.conf"
  )
  // Settings for every service, i.e. for admin and web subprojects
  def serviceSettings (module: String) = moduleSettings(module) ++: Seq(
    includeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "*.less",
    excludeFilter in (Assets, LessKeys.less) := "_*.less",
    pipelineStages := Seq(rjs, digest),
    RjsKeys.mainModule := s"main-$module"
  )

  val commonDependencies = Seq(
    javaJdbc,
    cache,
    javaWs,
    javaEbean,
    "com.newrelic.agent.java" % "newrelic-agent" % "3.7.0",
    "be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.3.3",
    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "2.4.1",
    ...
  )
```

Scala verison is 2.11.6 and sbt version is 0.13.5

This app is running well on my localhost. So I can't figure out what is happening with this sbt import error...

Comment: Try running it locally using foreman?

Comment: What version of sbt do you have configured in your `project/build.properties`. Also, might want to check your `modules/admin/build.sbt` for stray characters. but it looks like sbt is doing something weird.

Comment: I've just added some explanation on how the build.sbt file is generated. sbt version is 0.13.5

Comment: I'd suggest upgrading sbt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact my app need to clean up before compilation. Executing `heroku config:set SBT_CLEAN=true` will force sbt to clean artifacts on heroku before compilation. This has fixed the issue.